# FlorientR/laravel-gentelella bootstrap.min.css not found

Tags: laravel, gentelella

I installed FlorientR/laravel-gentelella, by cloning it with phpstrom.

I do not find the dir 'css' under 'public' Folder. So bootstrap.min.css (path: css/bootstrap.min.css) file is not loaded by the page.

What have I to do now? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

1. `npm install --global bower gulp`
2. `npm install`
3. `bower install`
4. `gulp`

Comment: npm install --global bower gulp command shows the following Errors...

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is nolonger maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it inthe tree